# loop function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am newbie in Codeigniter. This is one of my model function. there was a list of the data (student name,student ID,gender)with the same Course_ID.how do i print out all the list?is add in the loop function? Below function only cant print out one row of data.

```
>  public function viewMark($Course_ID)
>       {
>           //while($Course_ID != NULL)
>           if($Course_ID != NULL)
>           {
>               $this->db->select('*');
>               $this->db->where('mark.Course_ID',$Course_ID);
>               $this->db->from('mark');
>               
>               $query = $this->db->get();
>               
>               return $query->row();
>               
>           }
>       }
```

Comment: use `return $query->result()` or `return $query->result_array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function viewMark($Course_ID)
       {

           if(isset($Course_ID) && $Course_ID != NULL)
           {
              $this->db->select('*');
               $this->db->where('mark.Course_ID',$Course_ID);
              $this->db->from('mark');

              $query = $this->db->get();

              return $query->result();

          }
      }
```

Controller

```
public function fun($Course_ID){

  $this->load->model("your_model_class");


  $data['db_data'] = $this->your_model_class->viewMark($Course_ID);

  $this->load->view('page', $data);

}
```

in your view :

```
<?php foreach ($db_data as $row_data):?>
<?php echo $row_data->your_table_column_name?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
return $query->row();
```

to

```
return $query->result();
```

Then in your controller, you can do this:

```
public function whatever_this_is($Course_ID){

  $this->load->model("yourmodel");

  $data['mark'] = $this->yourmodel->viewMark($Course_ID);

  $this->load->view('page', $data);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
foreach ($mark as $m):
  echo $m->whatever."<br>";
  echo $m->something."<br>";
endforeach;
```